# How can I retrieve data from a json or format it better in django

Tags: json, django, templates, session, cart

I am trying to implement a shopping cart and i have created the following views. The first two, `cart_add(request, product_id)` and `cart_remove(request, product_id)` add and remove items from a cart stored in a session. Each of them then redirects to a `cart_detail(request)` view which returns the current content of the cart to a template.

```
@require_POST
def cart_add(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        cart.add(product=product, quantity=cd['quantity'], update_quantity=cd['update'])

    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')


def cart_remove(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    cart.remove(product)
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')


def cart_detail(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    return render(request, 'cart/detail.html', {'cart': cart})
```

I have added some products to the cart but the json i get looks like so:

```
{'product': '[{"model": "resource_manager.product", "pk": 6, "fields": {"created": "2016-04-17T12:33:43Z", "updated": "2016-04-18T10:45:17Z", "name": "Workbook", "image": "resource_manager/2016/04/18/20130405_171035.jpg"}}]', 'quantity': 12} 
{'product': '[{"model": "resource_manager.product", "pk": 1, "fields": {"created": "2016-04-16T04:13:34Z", "updated": "2016-04-17T12:25:45Z", "name": "Radio", "image": ""}}]', 'quantity': 2} 
{'product': '[{"model": "resource_manager.product", "pk": 2, "fields": {"created": "2016-04-16T11:15:57Z", "updated": "2016-04-17T12:25:45Z", "name": "Mat", "image": ""}}]', 'quantity': 9} 
{'product': '[{"model": "resource_manager.product", "pk": 4, "fields": {"created": "2016-04-17T07:42:54Z", "updated": "2016-04-17T12:25:45Z", "name": "Tablet", "image": ""}}]', 'quantity': 3}
```

QUESTION: How do I access the the name, of each product within the template `cart/detail.html`

Here is what i tried:

```
{% for item in cart %}
            {% with product=item.product %}
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">
                            <img src="{% if product.image %}{{ product.image.url }}{% else %}{% static "resource_manager/img/no_image.png" %}{% endif %}">
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.quantity }}</td>
                    <td><a href="{% url "cart:cart_remove" product.id %}">Remove</a></td>
                </tr>
            {% endwith %}
        {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. You just need to iterate through the values of the key `product`.

Here is one way of doing this:

```
{% for key, value in cart.items %}
    {% if key == 'product' %}
        {% for product in value %}
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">
                    <img src="{% if product.image %}{{ product.image.url }}{% else %}{% static "resource_manager/img/no_image.png" %}{% endif %}">
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.quantity }}</td>
            <td><a href="{% url "cart:cart_remove" product.id %}">Remove</a></td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        {# do something else.. #}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```